# Alphabet to numbers?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Why am i getting this error:

AlphaPos.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
      String letter = kbd.NextLine();

symbol:   method NextLine()
  location: variable kbd of type Scanner
1 error

It's probably something so simple.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlphaPos
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
         Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

  int position = 0;

  String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  String alphabetCAP = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  System.out.print("Please enter an upper or lower case letter:");
  String letter = kbd.NextLine();

  char L = letter.charAt(0);

 if(Character.isLowerCase(L))
 {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < alphabet.length()-1; i++)
    {
     if(alphabet.charAt(i) == L)
        position = i+1;
    }   
  System.out.print("You entered "+letter+" in upper case it is number "+ position +" in the alphabet.");      
   } 
   if(Character.isUpperCase(L))
  {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < alphabetCAP.length()-1; i++)
    {
     if(alphabetCAP.charAt(i) == L)
        position = i+1;
    }   
  System.out.print(" You entered "+letter+" in upper case it is number "+ position +" in the alphabet.");      
  }
  else 
     System.out.print(" You entered " +letter+ " and it is no in alphabet.");      


   }
 }
```

Comment: Where is javascript in it?

Comment: The method is `nextLine`, not `NextLine`

Comment: Is a type error, type kbd.nextLine() instead kbd.NextLine()

Comment: method names generally start with lower case letters in Java.

Comment: Yeah type error as mentioned. You should really pay attention to the error message, its important information, "AlphaPos.java:15: " means there is a problem on line 15, " find symbol" means you are trying to access something that doesnt exist. After you found this out the next call of action is to head to java documentation on the oracle website and search for scanners and look up the method

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your porblem is you are using Scanner.NextLine(), instead of Scanner.nextLine.

But to comment on your code its rather silly to define the alphabet then loop through to get the position, why not get the letter, force it to be either uppercase or lowercase and then take away 'a' or 'A' and add one, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // note the readable names, dont use "kbd" use something meaningful.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

    char letter = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    int position = (letter - 'a') + 1;

    System.out.println(position);
    input.close();
}
```

note you should really use patterns to ensure the input is in the form you want it to be, but im not doing everything for you. You can figure that one out yourself. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html